# Does Ruby has some APIs like select() in POSIX?

Tags: ruby

For example, if I create some UDP sockets to receive data in different ports.
How can I wait for them in one process simultaneously?

Thx:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Kernel#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-select) is what you’re after:

> Calls select(2) system call. It monitors given arrays of IO objects, waits one or more of IO objects ready for reading, are ready for writing, and have pending exceptions respectably, and returns an array that contains arrays of those IO objects. It will return nil if optional timeout value is given and no IO object is ready in timeout seconds.